# How can I use this code to parse two more files in Python 3?

Tags: python, function

I wrote the below program to search one file, so far. I have two more files I want to search. I believe functions should be able to do this, but I am not sure where to start. How do I get it to run the code on each file name instead of copying the entire code and replacing the relevant text?

```
# declares the files used
gameslist = 'gameslist.txt'
name1 = 'filename1' # I wrote the code for this one
# I want to change the code to do the next two files without repeating 
# it and changing the names, as that is inefficient.
name2 = 'filename2' 
name3 = 'filename3'

# imports the necessary libraries
import os, time
from stat import * # ST_SIZE etc

# finds the time the file was last modified and prints it
try:
    st = os.stat(name1)
except IOError:
    print("failed to get information about", name1)
else:
    print("At:", time.asctime(time.localtime(st[ST_MTIME])))

# checks the file for the string 'Minecraft'
if 'Minecraft' in open(name1).read():
   print('name1 was playing Minecraft')

# checks the file for the string 'LoL'
if 'LoL' in open(name1).read():
    print('name1 was playing LoL')
```

Comment: A bit lost here. In the try/except block, why would you print("failed...", name2) when the try block was called on name1?

Comment: That was a type-o. I had my daughter's name in there, and changed it to name1 throughout, and must have hit the wrong key.

Answer (score 0):

```
# declares the files used
gameslist = 'gameslist.txt'
filenames = ['filename1','filename2' ,'filename3']


for filename in filenames:
    # imports the necessary libraries
    import os, time
    from stat import * # ST_SIZE etc

    # finds the time the file was last modified and prints it
    try:
        st = os.stat(filename)
    except IOError:
        print("failed to get information about", filename)
    else:
        print("At:", time.asctime(time.localtime(st[ST_MTIME])))

    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        file_content = f.read()

    # checks the file for the string 'Minecraft'
    if 'Minecraft' in file_content:
       print('{} was playing Minecraft'.format(filename))

    # checks the file for the string 'LoL'
    if 'LoL' in file_content:
        print('{} was playing LoL'.format(filename))
```

You could put the stuff in the for loop in a function to make it more clean, but this is the general idea of using loops for this task.

Answer (score 0):

```
def search_in_file(string, file_name):
    current_file = open(file_name)
    if string in current_file.read():
        print('name1 was playing %s' % string)
    current_file.close()
```

Here's how you would use it:

```
search_in_file('Minecraft', name1)
search_in_file('LoL', name1)
```

Comment: Add an error catch for the file not existing and this is easily the best answer here imo.

Comment: In the line: print('name1 was playing %s' % string), won't that print "name1" every time?

Comment: Well, yes.
You can also make "name1" a variable if you'd please.